# Fullcalendar half of timeGridWeek is viewing like a dayGridWeek

Tags: html, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar in angular 7, rest of the view like month and list are working fine , i thing something issue in timeGrid. i

HTML Code

```
 <full-calendar height="parent" #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [header]="header"
            [nowIndicator]="true"  deepChangeDetection="true">
</full-calendar>
```

JS COde

```
@ViewChild('calendar', { static: false }) calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, timelinePlugin, listPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin];
header = {
    left: 'prev,next, today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
};
```

[image]

Comment: Okey this is time grid. Day and time has only time difference

Comment: what does it mean time difference , i do not have events

Comment: The most likely explanation for this is that you forgot to load one or more required CSS files for fullCalendar, or that the CSS you are using is causing an issue - did you try to customise the fullCalendar CSS, or overwrite its rules with your own? Or use a custom theme that could have mistakes? Or maybe just some other CSS meant for another part of your application is causing a conflict. You might be able to get clues using your browser's element inspector in the developer tools. Anyway strip the page back to the default fullCalendar CSS, make sure you included all files, and then try again

Comment: i dont think so , i used all , might be some conflict with theme css